# Discrete bar with highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

Can someone point me in the right direction? I'd like to build a bar chart using highcharts with values both above and below the X axis - http://nvd3.org/examples/discreteBar.html

Something like this - but the axis here is on the Y axis, I'd like that on the X axis. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-negative-stack

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Example: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-negative

Answer (score 2):

To move to vertical bars, you need to change the chart type:

```
chart: {
     type: 'column'
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s29xbgLc/